# BackBtn does not cancel timer from previous scene

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk, back-button, cancellation

I can't find the correct code to cancel the timers from previous scenes. I have tried these combinations in various positions:

```
      if "tap" == true then
           timer.cancel()
      end

           timer.cancel(event.source)

      timer.cancel = true

      timer.stop

    if "tap" == true then
            timer.cancel = true
            timer.stop()
    end
```

...and so on. Can someone point me to the correct code and where exactly to place it? Thanks.
These are the scenes in question:

### -- info.lua

```
local composer = require "composer"
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create(event)
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local widget = require "widget"
    local scene1Btn
    local function onScene1BtnRelease()
            composer.gotoScene("scene1", "fade", 40)
            return true 
    end

    scene1Btn = widget.newButton{
            defaultFile = "images/reviewTwo.png",
            width= 480, height= 320,
            onRelease = onScene1BtnRelease 
    }

    sceneGroup:insert(scene1Btn)
end

scene:addEventListener("create", scene)

return scene
```

### -- scene1.lua

```
    local myData = require ("myData")

    local composer = require ( "composer")
    local scene = composer.newScene()

            local function showScene2()
                    local options = {
                            effect = "slideLeft",
                            time = 130,
                    }
    composer.gotoScene("scene2", options)
    end

   -- create scene 

    function scene:createScene ( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    end     

    function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

-- will                                                                     

    if ( phase == "will") then
            data = data + 1
                    if data == 5 then
                    sub = sub + 1
                    data = 1
            end
            if sub == 3 then
            section = section + 1
                    sub = 1
                    data = 1
            end

            background = display.newImage( "images/staveBlankgrey2.png", 240, 160 )
            note1 = display.newImage( "images/crDown.png", 130, 141 )
            count = display.newImage( workoutTable[section][sub][data], 60, 40 ) 

            sceneGroup:insert( background )
            sceneGroup:insert( note1 )
            sceneGroup:insert( count )


-- goBackBtn                                                                                

            local object = display.newImage("images/goBackBtn.png", 240, 250)
            object.name = "button object"

            local function onObjectTap( self, event )
                    composer.gotoScene( "info" )
                    return true
            end
            object.tap = onObjectTap
            object:addEventListener( "tap", object )
            sceneGroup:insert( object )

-- did                                                                                                                 

     elseif ( phase == "did") then
            local function showScene2()
                 local options = {
                    effect = "slideLeft",
                    time = 30,
                 }
            composer.gotoScene( "scene2", options )
            end

            timer.performWithDelay( tempo, showScene2 )
            end
     end     

-- hide / destroy

    function scene:hide( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
            local phase = event.phase
    end

    function scene:destroy( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

    return scene
```

### -- scene2.lua

```
    local composer = require ( "composer")
    local scene = composer.newScene()

            local function showScene1()
                    local options = {
                            effect = "slideLeft",
                            time = 130,
                    }
            composer.gotoScene("scene1", options)
            end

-- create scene 

    function scene:createScene ( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    end     

    function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

-- will

    if ( phase == "will") then
     background = display.newImage( "images/staveBlankgrey2.png", 240, 160 )
     note1 = display.newImage( "images/mmDown.png", 130, 172 )

    sceneGroup:insert( background )
    sceneGroup:insert( note1 )


-- goBackBtn 

   local object = display.newImage("images/goBackBtn.png", 240, 250)
       object.name = "button object"

       local function onObjectTap( self, event )
            composer.gotoScene( "info" )
            return true
       end
   object.tap = onObjectTap
   object:addEventListener( "tap", object )
                    sceneGroup:insert( object )

-- did

   elseif ( phase == "did") then
       local function showScene1()
           local options = {
                effect = "slideLeft",
                time = 30,
                                    }
       composer.gotoScene( "scene1", options )
       end

       timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showScene1 )
     end 
    end     


-- hide / destroy

    function scene:hide( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
            local phase = event.phase
    end

    function scene:destroy( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

    return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

As I assume, you want to cancel timer when you go to another scene. Simply use a reference to the timer:

```
local myTimer1 = timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showScene1 )
```

And then just cancel it in scene:hide or scene: destroy or anywhere else you want to.

```
if myTimer1 then 
    timer.cancel(myTimer1)
    myTimer1 = nil
end
```

Of course you have to declare timer variable (`myTimer1`) in a place where you'll have an access to it. In main scope for example

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work. Shouldn't the cancellation be related to the backBtn?

Comment: You only need to cancel the timer if it is working, and this is not your case. You timer only executes once calling the showSceneX() that will execute the gotoScene() function, at this point the timer is finished so you can not cancel the timer in hide/destroy scene functions. You only need to cancel the timer if the timer executes several times and you want to stop it before change scenes.

Comment: Thanks Koormo. The timer is always working. It times the different scenes in and out like a slideshow. The backBtn should be able to cancel the timer at any moment and send the show back to info.lua with the timer now inactive so the show stops there. But the timer continues and the slideshow resumes where it left off. I'm mystified.

Comment: Then Lukis was right, declare a timer variable at beginning of your scene and use the cancel in the hide scene phase, so when your scene changes when you hit back button the cancel will be executed